# Why is the Cell next to my formula repeating?

Tags: excel, sumifs

[Cell I14 is repeating Cell H14 Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JHra.png)

Every time i enter this type for SumIFS formula the sell in the adjecent Column will populate with the same formula. I cant type over it or delete.

Comment: Your Formula is `Spill`ing because it's returning an array.

Comment: you can check on you tube "Excel dynamic arrays". Maybe a @ behind the = sign will do what you want or you wrap your formula in a Sum(SumIfs...). But check if your result will be what you want.